# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getWord()

Tags: php

не могу понять в чем проблема ?

```html
<?php
 function getWord($w){
  $l = getLang();
  
  $s['Exit']['kz'] = 'ШЫҒУ';
  $s['Exit']['ru'] = 'ВЫХОД';
  $s['Exit']['en'] = 'EXIT';
  
    $s['INFORMATION ON SOLD GOODS ON']['kz'] = 'САТЫП АЛУ ТУРАЛЫ АҚПАРАТ';
  $s['INFORMATION ON SOLD GOODS ON']['ru'] = 'СВЕДЕНИЯ О ПРОДАННОМ ТОВАРЕ НА';
  $s['INFORMATION ON SOLD GOODS ON']['en'] = 'INFORMATION ON SOLD GOODS ON';
  if($s[$w][$l]!=''){return $s[$w][$l];}else {return $w;}
 }
?>
```

пишет ошибку Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getWord() (previously declared in путь... помогите пожалуйста!и еще  я новичок что мне следует по читать чтобы понять такие ошибки в будущем!

Comment: скорее всего инклудите файл несколько раз. можете обернуть все это дело в `if(!function_exists(...))`, но лучше просто избегать таких ситуаций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас функция getWord определена где-то ещё (возможно в другом файле, который Вы подключаете совместно с этим файлом). Сделайте разные названия функциям или (более сложный вариант) используйте пространства имен.